# How to open a window from mac terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

this is the first time I ask on stackoverflow because I can't find the answer anywhere. I use emacs to write all my code and I just switched from ubuntu to mac os. One problem has been bothering me: How could you open emacs window from mac terminal just like you would open firefox window from terminal on Linux system? I know the way it works for Linux system is that, whenever you type a command from terminal, the terminal search for the binary in you PATH and execute it. Is it the case for Mac that you can only open applicaiton in window form under "/Application" directory and all binaries opened from terminal are in non-window form? Big thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

The pre-installed Emacs that comes with OS X is built without the GUI.  Hence

```
$ emacs   # in the shell/terminal
```

will *NOT* open a graphical window, and instead will open up the text/terminal version instead.  Note that this version (installed at `/usr/bin/emacs`) is also old, and is at 22.1.1 in Mountain Lion.

To get the behavior you desire (and also get the latest version of Emacs as a bonus), you can download the latest Emacs build.  This is available at various places, including http://emacsforosx.com/.

Most of these pre-built Emacs are installed under `/Applications`, and in order to invoke from the terminal, you will need to specify the full path to the binary, which usually is:

```
 /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

You can create a simple alias to this binary in your `.bashrc` as:

```
 alias emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

and then invoke emacs in its full glory from the command line.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much Anupam! I actually tried emacsforosx.com and I didn't know where the binary goes. Now I know it's under MacOS/Emacs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried

> /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal &

and it did open a new window just fine.

OS X 10.7.4 here.

EDIT: Indeed if I try:

> open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

No new terminal window is opened

But,

> open --new /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

works also, and is probably better than my first option because the job is not tied to the terminal you started the new terminal with.

Answer (score 2):

First, download a Mac OS/X emacs build from here: http://emacsformacosx.com/

Second, once it's installed, you can:

1. Open it from the command line with `open -a emacs`
2. Set it to run server mode in your .emacs init, and then at the
   command line type `emacsclient foo` for file `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend either getting emacs via fink, or going to here: http://emacsformacosx.com/

This will allow you to install a local version of emacs that runs through the X server, and thus has the full GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if u're looking for something like this

open /path/to/some.app

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not describe my problem clearly. I was trying to type "emacs" command and I expected a Emacs window pop out, just like what will happen on Linux system. But it seems like I can only start a terminal version of emacs that way, without the open /some.app trick.